# C++: about precision of calculating (code is inside)

Tags: c++, taylor-series

Can you give me advice about precision of computing Taylor series for an exponent? We have a degree of exponent and a figure of precision calculating as imput data. We should recieve a calculating number with a given precision as output data. I wrote a program, but when I calculate an answer and compare it with embedded function's answer, it has differents. Can you advice me, how I can destroy a difference between answeres? [formula of exponent's calculating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPn9q.png)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <math.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int Factorial(int n);
double Taylor(double x, int q);
int main()
{
    double res = 0;
    int q = 0;
    double number = 0;
    cout << "Enter positive number" << "\n";
    cin >> number;
    cout << "Enter rounding error (precision)" << "\n";
    cin >> q;
    cout << "\n" << "\n";
    res = Taylor(number, q);
    cout << "Answer by Taylor : " << res;
    cout << "Answer by embedded function: " << exp(number);
    Sleep(25000);

    return 0;
}

int Factorial(int n) {              
    int res = 1;
    int i = 2;
    if (n == 1 || n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        while (i <= n)
        {
            res *= i;
            i++;
        }
        return res;
    }
}

double Taylor(double x, int q) {
    double res = 1;
    double res1 = 0;
    int i =1;
    while (i)
    {
        res += (pow(x, i) / Factorial(i));
        if (int(res*pow(10, q)) < (res*pow(10, q)))
        {//rounding res below
            if ( ( int (res * pow(10,q+1)) - int(res*pow(10, q))) <5 )
                res1 = (int(res*pow(10, q))) * pow(10, (-q));
            else
                res1 = (int(res*pow(10, q))) * pow(10, (-q)) + pow(10,-q);

            return res1;

        }

        i++;

    } 


}
```

Comment: What is the difference? What function do you try to expand?

Comment: I want to make Taylor's function more accurately like embedded function. For example, you can try enter variables and you will see a difference in answers.

Comment: what are the results you get, how do they differ from what you would like to get?

Comment: @tryuf At least, fix all of the warnings before asking, since they may be the cause for your issue: `warning C4715: 'Taylor' : not all control paths return a value`.

Comment: if I enter e^5 and rounding error 4 my function will return me a figure 39,3334. Embedded function returns another answer: 148,413

Comment: @tryuf In addition: did you try stepping through your code, line by line, with a debugger, to see where the code starts doing something you didn't expect?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, I checked a code few times

Comment: @tryuf That is not what I asked. I'll ask once again: Did you **step through** your code with a debugger? If no, then do that.

Comment: if one result it 39,334 and the other 148,413 then most likely it is not a matter of precicion, but more likely that your result is just plain wrong

Comment: @tobi303 Well.. I looked through his code.. And his precision calculation is, indeed, at fault. It _thinks_ that it reached the result up to a necessary precision, when it didn't.

Comment: int Factorial(int n);  For a 32bit int this breaks for any n > 12

Comment: To avoid overflow, use `(x ^ i) / i! = (x ^ (i-1))/(i-1)! * x/i`

Comment: Side note: for better grades, find a way to determine the precision that doesn't involve computing powers of 10.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code. First, the factorial is very prone to overflow. Actually I dont know when overflow occurs for `int` factorials, but I remember that eg on usual pocket calculators `x!` overflows already for `x==70`. You probably dont need that high factorials, but still it is better to avoid that problem right from the start. If you look at the correction that needs to be added in each step: `x^i / i!` (maths notation) then you notice that this value is actually much smaller than `x^i` or `i!` respectively. Also you can calculate the value easily from the previous one by simply multiplying it by `x/i`.

Second, I dont understand your calculations for the precision. Maybe it is correct, but to be honest for me it looks too complicated to even try to understand it ;).

Here is how you can get the correct value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct taylor_result {
        int iterations;
        double value;
        taylor_result() : iterations(0),value(0) {}
};

taylor_result taylor(double x,double eps = 1e-8){
    taylor_result res;
    double accu = 1;                           // calculate only the correction
                                               // but not its individual terms
    while(accu > eps){                        
         res.value += accu;
         res.iterations++;
         accu *= (x / (res.iterations));
    }
    return res;
}       

int main() {
    std::cout << taylor(3.0).value << "\n";
    std::cout << exp(3.0) << "\n";
}
```

Note that I used a struct to return the result, as you should pay attention to the number of iterations needed.

PS: see [here](http://ideone.com/OGERIM) for a modified code that lets you use a already calculated result to continue the series for better precision. Imho a nice solution should also provide a way to set a limit for the number of iterations, but this I leave for you to implement ;)